# insert the value of the checked ccheckbox in mysql vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

how to get the value of the checked check box in data grid view and insert the selected row in database mysql.

i have the column names cloth_id, cloth_desc quantity and price
if the check box in the row was checked then the quantity and price will be multiplied to get the total amount to be paid. thanks in advance :)
This code is good for only 1 row. help me in query when multiple row was checked.
thanks :)

```
 If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    Dim amount, qty, prod As Double
    row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    amount = row.Cells("Price").Value.ToString
    qty = row.Cells("Qty").Value.ToString
    prod = amount * qty
    kg.Text = prod
End If
```

Comment: Go through all rows with `For Each` loop, check if `CheckBox` is checked, if so then use your code for creating sql query. After loop if query contains new rows run it...

Answer (score 0):

Try This Coding

```
Dim checkBox1 As CheckBoxlist = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex) .FindControl("Checkbox1")
    if checkbox1.checked=true then
        For Each li As ListItem In checkBox1 .Items
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        Dim amount, qty, prod As Double
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        amount = row.Cells("Price").Value.ToString
        qty = row.Cells("Qty").Value.ToString
        prod = amount * qty
        kg.Text = prod
        next
    End If
    else
    End If
```

Comment: `datagridview` is `Winform`'s control.